# Clear apps from Android Market dashboard

Tags: android, google-play

A few of my apps were pulled by Google, and a few I unpublished myself, but my [Android Market dashboard](http://market.android.com/publish/Home) still has all these apps listed. Is there any way to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

For now there is no way to remove them for good. You can only unpublish them. I also think that they should make better UI for managing our apps. This is to simple, and it should not be hard to make it much better.